# Netlify.toml vs netlify.yaml

Tags: deployment, netlify

I am a little confused by the new configuration file netlify.yaml.
I imagined it would be a drop-in replacement for netlify.toml, but without the toml file I get the following error:

```
No netlify.toml found. This is needed to configure the function settings. For more info: https://github.com/netlify/netlify-lambda#installation
```

When both of them are present I have

```
 failed during stage 'Reading and parsing configuration files': Multiple potential Netlify configuration files in "/opt/build/repo": netlify.toml, netlify.yaml
```

I would like to access the “plugins” functionality and I am not certain if it exists on the toml version of the configuration as this doesn’t seem to trigger anything:

```
[[plugins]]
  type = "./.netlify/plugins/xxx"
```

What would you recommend as the best course of action?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the response I have received on the community forum (https://community.netlify.com/t/netlify-toml-vs-netlify-yaml/6482/2):

```
We haven’t quite finished implementing the json and yml support, but these are the docs: https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration/#json-and-yaml-configuration-files .

It is definitely not implemented in the private beta for build plugins yet, so you’ll need to stick with toml as the docs advise.
```